# SessionNotCreatedException: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location

Tags: robotframework, geckodriver

I was trying to do a basic robot test case as below. Geckodriver was placed under Python37/Scripts folder and same is available under path.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${URL}      https://www.google.com
${Browser}      firefox

*** Test Cases ***
Testing with Browser
        open browser    ${URL}      ${Browser}
```

Running above test case resulted in this error - **Unable to open Firefox browser due to error - SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line**

I have red some previously answered queries to use absolute path of the firefox, can someone please help to get this done in my robot file ?..

Code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***

${URL}      https://www.google.com
${Browser}      firefox

*** Test Cases ***
Testing with Browser
        open browser    ${URL}      ${Browser}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to not finding the binary of Firefox, not `geckodriver`, which you already solved.

To be sure `firefox` is in the directories set in the PATH environment variable, you should open a Command Window/Terminal/Shell and try:

```
firefox --version
```

If not the expected version, and an error, the path to the binary must be given in `Open Browser`option, or the correct directory listed in PATH environment variable.

You can use the option `executable_path`, but be aware of this note in the `Open Browser` documentation:

```
The executable_path argument is new in SeleniumLibrary 4.2.
```